# Django settings settings module programmatically at runtime based on environment

Tags: python, django

I have a `dev` and `prod` environment, I am trying to programmatically assign the settings module based on an environment variable `DEV` so fat my settings have the following structure:

```
project
--settings
----__init__.py
----common.py
----dev.py
----prod.py
```

inside my `__init__.py` I have:

```
import os

if os.environ['DEV_ENV']:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings.dev'
else:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings.prod'
```

However, when I run `python3 manage.py migrate` I get this error:

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

however if I run with `--settings` flag manually, it works

`python3 manage.py migrate --settings=project.settings.dev`

Comment: As it is, you're safe, but don't do this: https://www.pydanny.com/using-executable-code-outside-version-control.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try in `__init__.py`

```
import os
from .common import *

environment = os.environ.get("DEV_ENV")

if environment == development: #assuming value of DEV_ENV is 'development'
    from .dev import *
else:
    from .prod import *
```

this will load the development settings module if the value of DEV_ENV is set to development, otherwise by default it will load the production settings module.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic should work within the `manage.py` script.

Alternatively, I would consider just setting `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` wherever you set `DEV_ENV` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found [Python Decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) library and it's awesome for this purpose.

How I use it?
I create a `.env` file in the project directory, I have an example template for my use case:

```
MODE=local
DEBUG=True
DB_NAME=hood
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=abc123
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
SENTRY_DNS={{sentry_dns}}
```

and then in my `__init__.py` I decide environment based off of values in this file

example:

```
from decouple import config

mode = config('MODE')

if mode == 'dev':
    from .development import *
elif mode == 'prod':
    from .production import *
else:
    from .local import *
```

This solves 2 main purposes:

- it solves the **which env I'm using now** problem
- it allows you to put passwords and env variables away from your git repository